# Decoding Http Response Content from Russian (Cyrillic)

Tags: c#, encoding

I send a request to an API and the server sends some portion of its response in Russian. I url decode the response using code page 1251 encoding but still don't get the result I want.

How can I convert the response back to plain english? What encoding do I use?

Comment: Please share some example strings so that we can further understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to convert Russian letters (Cyrillic) to Latin ones you can use Dictionary structure with Cyrillic-Latin relationship.

```
var map = new Dictionary<char, string>
{
    { 'Ж', "G" },
    { 'е', "e" },
    { 'ф', "f" },
    { 'Й', "Y" },
    ...
}

var result = string.Concat("Россия".Select(c => map[c]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. This looks like it would work however isn't there another way that isn't manual?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your intention correctly, but in case of `HttpClient` you can work with `Windows-1251` (or another encoding) like this:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("requestUri");
    var httpContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    string responseString = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(httpContent, 0, httpContent.Length);

    // - check status code
    // (int)httpResponse.StatusCode
    // - and here's your response
    // responseString
}
```

If `responseString` still contains some gibberish, then I would assume that this server uses not `Windows-1251` but some other encoding, so first you'll need to establish which one exactly.

**P.S.** For `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)` to work you might need to install `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` NuGet package and register encoding provider:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```